# Get string after a line with a certain word

Tags: awk, sed

With openwrt I usually use UCI to get data in variables for some scripts. Something like that:

```
uci get /etc/config/network.lan.data
```

Unfortunately I did not find something similar for Linux in general but I believe that awk or sed can do it without needing numerous outputs.

In general, the first string is only a parameter to find the second

input:

```
    ...

config 'wan'
    data 'a1 a2 a3'
    something 'words'

config 'lan'
    info 'words'
    data 'b1 b2 b3'
    something 'words'

config 'net'
    something 'words'
    info 'words'
    data 'c1 c2'

    ...
```

Output:

```
b1 b2 b3
```

--- Edit: --

I believe that with the input of this form would be broader the functionality of the script:

input:

```
    ...

config something 'wan'
    something some_data 'a1 a2 a3'
    something 'words'

config something 'lan'
    something some_info 'words'
    something some_data 'b1 b2 b3'
    something 'words'

config something 'net'
    something 'words'
    something some_info 'words'
    something some_data 'c1 c2'

    ...
```

Attention to requests, here a better explanation:

1 - find line with 'lan' (or maybe  with config.*.'lan')

2 - If found, search the following lines for the first line with a word ending data (maybe *.data)

3 - Print the content between ' ' of this line

Output:

```
b1 b2 b3
```

What is the best solution?

Grateful for the attention!

Comment: Not clear enough, could you please do let me know from where to perform search in Input_file? Kindly be more clear on this.

Comment: If you're assuming we know what `openwrt I usually use UCI` to state your requirements then YMMV. Tell us what the criteria is for outputting `b1 b2 b3` as there are several alternatives and several possible ways to implement solutions, (2nd occurrence of `data`? Block containing `lan`? Something else?), hence the eclectic selection of answers you have so far!

Comment: 1 - Search for the first line that has 'lan' (or "something. *.' Lan '"); 2 - if it is found below the first line containing "date" and print the values between ' '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
awk -v C="lan" -v F="data" '$1=="config" { gsub(/^[\47"]|[\47"]$/,"",$2); conf=$2; next } conf==C && $1==F { $1=""; gsub(/^ *[\47"]|[\47"]$/, ""); print }' YOURFILE
```

Input:

```
config 'wan'
    data 'a1 a2 a3'
    something 'words'

config 'lan'
    info 'words'
    data 'b1 b2 b3'
    something 'words'

config 'net'
    something 'words'
    info 'words'
    data 'c1 c2'
```

Output:

```
b1 b2 b3
```

---

Slightly different approach for the updated question:

```
awk -v C="lan" -v F="data" 'BEGIN { FS="\47"; REG=".*"F"[ \t]*" } $1~"config[ \t]" { conf=$2 } conf==C && $1~REG { print $2 }' YOURFILE
```

Input:

```
config something 'wan'
    something some_data 'a1 a2 a3'
    something 'words'

config something 'lan'
    something some_info 'words'
    something some_data 'b1 b2 b3'
    something 'words'

config something 'net'
    something 'words'
    something some_info 'words'
    something some_data 'c1 c2'
```

Output:

```
b1 b2 b3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    RS=""                      # empty RS separates record by empty lines
    FS=" *\47[\n ]*"           # FS is a single quote surrounded by space and \n
}
match($0,"config" FS "lan") {  # if record has proper config line
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)        # iterate keys
        if($i=="data")         # if data found
            print $(i+1)       # print its value
}' file
b1 b2 b3
```

Comment: Pretty, but it places more assumptions on the data, like records separated by an empty line, field values necessarily start with a single quote, only a single field value (would drop some data for `data 'b1 b2 b3' 'b4 b5'`).

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Did you prepare for `data 'b1 b2 b3' 'b4 b5'` in your solution?

Comment: No, but since my solution just outputs everything after the field name only trimming quotes from both sides, it would output `b1 b2 b3' 'b4 b5` which is safer.

Comment: What do you mean by _more words_. Please post matching data for that request.

Comment: i mod your code with .* in ##($0,"config.*" FS "lan")##  and work for input:
    config something 'lan'  
                ###But i can't do this with  ###"if($i=="*.data")### : something some_data 'b1 b2 b3'

Comment: I wanted add .* before "data" for inputs like "something data 'b1 b2 b3'

Comment: It won't be able to handle that. It only reads `key 'value'`pairs.

Comment: And don't post that as an edit, rather make a new question. It will attract more people.

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) you can treat each section as a record by setting `RS` to the empty string and every line as a field by setting `FS` to new-line.

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN {
  RS = ""
  FS = "\n"
  q  = "'"      # Convenient definition of the quote character
}

$1 ~ q c q {
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
    if( $i ~ /^ *data / ) {
      split($i, a, q)
      print a[2]
    }
  }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk -v c=lan dims
```

Output:

```
b1 b2 b3
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

cat sedscript

```
:A
/^config/!d
/lan/!d
:B
N
s/.*\n//
/^config/bA
/.*data[^']*/!bB
s///
:C
s/([^']*)(')([^']*.*)/\1\3/
tC
p
bB
```

and you call it like that

```
sed -nEf sedscript infile
```